# how to acces on my data observable

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I do not know how to access on my data observable "pseudo".

I would click on the button and pass in my post the value of pseudo user and content message

```js
onAddPost() {
  this.afs.collection('posts')
  .add({
    'pseudo': this.auth.user.pseudo,
    'content': this.content});
  }
}
//the propriete 'pseudo' didnt exist on the observable <User> 

// but in my auth.service i have 
interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  pseudo?: string;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
    <div  
    style="width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.1);
    Max-height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
                <div class="float-left p-3 mb-2 bg-primary">
                    {{ post.data?.pseudo  }} 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="p-3 mb-2 text-left">{{ post.data.content }}</p>
                </div>
    </div></div>
    <div>
            <div class="form-group float-left ">
                <textarea  
                    rows="1"
                    [(ngModel)]="content" 
                    name="content"
                    placeholder="message.."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddPost()">envoyer</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and if I click, I have an error.  I would like to send data from my user with my button:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
    <div  
    style="width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.1);
    Max-height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
                <div class="float-left p-3 mb-2 bg-primary">
                    {{ post.data?.pseudo  }} 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="p-3 mb-2 text-left">{{ post.data.content }}</p>
                </div>
    </div></div>
    <div>
            <div class="form-group float-left ">
                <textarea  
                    rows="1"
                    [(ngModel)]="content" 
                    name="content"
                    placeholder="message.."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddPost()">envoyer</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me ?
Thank you

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: oups sorry :
ERROR Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom AngularFirestoreCollection object (found in field pseudo)
    at new FirestoreError

Comment: What is `this.auth.user.pseudo` supposed to be? As far as I know a Firebase Authentication user profile doesn't have a `pseudo` property, so that would be `undefined` with isn't a valid value to store into Firestore.

Comment: in my firebase auth.user i have: email, displayName, uid and i added pseudo and town. i can acces from other compenent that works 

if i want to acces i just specifi  user = this.auth.user;
and in my html {{ user.uid}} or {{ user.pseudo }} works

but that dosnt work when i want to put in my add function

Comment: any one  to hel me i try many thing but i dont know where i have to looking for ?
 > pseudo = this.user.pseudo
 > pseudo = this.afs.collection(`users`).doc(`pseudo`);
  >pseudo = this.afs.doc("user/pseudo");
  >pseudo = this.afs.collection(`users`)
  >pseudo = this.afs.doc<User>(`user/${this.auth.user}`)
  .valueChanges();
  >pseudo = JSON.stringify(this.afs.collection(`users`). doc ( 'uid' ));

any thing work and i dont if is because is on firebasecloud or if is my code